# display column width not working

Tags: css

I am not able to give specific width to display column, Here is my code

```
<display:table name="" htmlId="" class="display-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width :100%">
    ...                                                 
   <display:column title="" style="width: 20%;">
    ...                                                     
</display:table>
```

Here is css I tried

```
.display-table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100% }
.display-table td { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

But it always display records with equal with of all column to table. I am not able to modify with of this particular column.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3Vr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `table-layout: fixed;` , since that will make the column size equal

```
.display-table {  width: 100% }
```

Comment: *I am not able to modify with of this particular column.*